# Is there a way to obtain the original post body in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slack, slack-commands

I'm attempting to [verify a slack request](https://api.slack.com/docs/verifying-requests-from-slack) in spring boot 2.1. I can correctly compute the hash in a unit test. However, I cannot get the verification to work when the server handles an actual request. This is because the order of the url parameters changes between the initial request and the time the controller is invoked.

You can reproduce this using the example controller and curl below. Notice that the form payload in the curl is `hello=world&foo=baz&two=three` and the response is reordered to `two=three&foo=baz&hello=world`.

### Theory

I believe this is happening [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpRequest.java#L205-L213). Spring detects that form data has been posted, then encodes the form parameters, and writes them to a new input stream. It appears that the map that is iterated over to encode the params does not retain the original order.

### Question

Is there a way to obtain the original post body?

---

### Reproduce

```java
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class SlackController {
    @RequestMapping(
            path = "slack/command",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE },
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
    public String executeCommand(
            @RequestBody String requestBody
    ) {
        return requestBody;
    }
}
```

```
$ curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/slack/command' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     -H 'Accept: text/plain' \
     -d 'hello=world&foo=baz&two=three'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2019 05:26:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 29

two=three&foo=baz&hello=world
```

Comment: The request you send is seen ad 3 different variables send and that is also what you receive. If there is no relation in the varaibles why does the order matter to you? If you want a specific string returned, you should send the info as a single string.

Comment: @Runningriot, the request is generated by [Slack](https://slack.com) and contains a request header that includes a hash value for the request body, treated as a string. The Spring Boot request handler receives a different string as the request body. Although the body contains the same parameters as those sent, they are in a different order, which means that as strings, what was sent is different from what was received. Then, if the request handler attempts to compute the hash for the request body, it will be different, as it was computed for a totally different string.

Comment: Does reading from `ServletServerHttpRequest.getServletRequest().getInputStream()` help?

Comment: Thanks @manish I'll try to access that and let you know what I find.

Comment: @manish that worked. Can you please submit a answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Code:

```
    @RequestMapping(
            path = "slack/commands/joek",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE })
    public Map<String, Object> executeCommand(
            final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest
    ) {
        try {
       System.out.println(StreamUtils.copyToString(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```